# grocery crud model-database updating

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

```
public function services()
    {
        $username=$this->session->userdata('username');
        if($username!='')
        {
            $crud = new grocery_CRUD();


            $crud->set_table('tbl_services');

            $crud->set_subject('Services');
            $crud->columns('s_id','s_companyname','s_type','s_country','s_state','s_district','s_email','s_mobile','s_photo','s_active');
            $crud->set_relation('s_type','tbl_service_cat','service_desc');
            $crud->set_relation('s_country','tbl_country','country');
            $crud->set_relation('s_state','tbl_state','state');

            $crud->set_relation('s_district','tbl_district','district');
            $crud->set_field_upload('s_photo','uploads');
            $crud->callback_after_update(array($this,'rename_serviceimg_db'));
            $crud->callback_after_insert(array($this,'rename_serviceimg_db'));

            //$crud->set_relation('q_id','tbl_discussionanswer','q_id');
            $output = $crud->render();
            $this->_admin_output($output);
            }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
```

this is my controller function.in this type,country,dist,state are inserted as respective id in database. but i want the name itself.

Comment: name is self means??

Comment: when i choose the country as canada ,in database the correspondind id of canada is inserted,.i want the country name .